# Decoding algorithm to return location of subsequence in De Bruijn sequence

Tags: python, sequence, decode, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) for De Bruijn sequence provides an algorithm for construction De Bruijn sequences. Without constructing the De Bruijn sequences I would like an algorithm (preferably in python) which given an alphabet of size K subsequences length N and a specified subsequence S would return the starting list index position of the subsequence S in the De Bruijn sequence generated from K, N.

To be clear, I do not what to actually construct the De Bruijn sequence only compute the location of subsequences.

Is seems clear that the algorithm to compute the location of subsequences would be pair or specific to an algorithm to compute De Bruijn sequence.

Comment: Feed "de bruijn sequences with efficient decoding algorithms" to a search engine.  That's your first clue ;-)  That is, in *general* the decoding problem is computationally expensive.  When efficient decoding is important, it's important to construct the sequence with that in mind to begin with.  I don't know of any truly "simple" way, though.

Comment: @Tim Peters, thanks for the excellent search suggestion. Google is no good if you don't know what to search for. Lots of good stuff to read/learn now.